# Displaying VideoView in Dialog in android

Tags: android, dialog, android-videoview

I want to display a `VideoView` inside a Dialog in android, but I can't control the `MediaController` as the Video seems to appear behind, and the video appears darker .?
How to solve this issue ?

Answer (score 0):

I suggest that you need to use an `Activity` instead of a `Dialog`. Set your `Activity` theme to emulate a `Dialog` in the manifest.

**Example** - AndroidManifest.xml:

```
android:theme="@android:style/Theme.Dialog"
```

Then, you will be able to display a `VideoView` as in the examples.

Answer (score 0):

Use:
`videoView.setZOrderOnTop(true);`
and the video will not appear darker.